# implement marklogic envelop pattern

Tags: marklogic

An xml document have been loaded into Marklogic 8 as it is. The URI is `book1.xml`. There are hundreds of thousands of these kind of xml documents have been loaded into the Marklogic 8 as it is. I need to implement envelop pattern on those xml document. How do I update the document with envelop pattern?

Envelop pattern -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<envelop>    
    <meta-data>        
       <Id>1</Id>
       <createDate>2015-7-01</createDate>
       <createUserId>100</createUserId>
    </meta-data>
    <original>
       test1.xml
    </original>
</envelop>
```

book1.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <book xmlns="http://www.mybook.com"   
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <bookId>1</bookId>
       <title>Math 101</title>
       <author>John Smith</author>
       <price>100</price>
   </book>
```

Comment: Can you check your post?  I'm guessing there's XML that's not indented four spaces so stackoverflow can treat it as pre-formatted code.

Comment: Not sure what the envelop pattern is. Can you show the end result you want?

Comment: ok it is defined here http://www.xmlpatterns.com/EnvelopeMain.shtml

Answer (score 1):

in order to reprocess such a large number of documents, have a look at [CoRB2](https://github.com/marklogic/corb2) or [taskbot](https://github.com/mblakele/taskbot).

You'll probably find the [properties document](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/properties) useful for keeping track of which files have been updated.

Hope that points you in the right direction!
Ed